# Using Node.js addons in Electron's renderer with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, node-serialport

I have the following renderer:

```
import SerialPort from "serialport";

new SerialPort("/dev/tty-usbserial1", { baudRate: 57600 });
```

It's built by Webpack, with the following config (trimmed for brevity):

```
const config = {
  entry: { renderer: ["./src/renderer"] }
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  target: "electron-renderer",
  node: false, // Disables __dirname mocking and such
};
```

It's served by a development server, along with an `index.html`, and is loaded by the main process as a web page (this is needed for hot module replacement during development).

The main process is built by Webpack and emitted to `dist` too. A Webpack plugin also generates the following `dist/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

When I run `electron dist`, the renderer process crashes with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28)
    at dirname (path.js:1364)
    at Function.getRoot (bindings.js?dfc1:151)
    at bindings (bindings.js?dfc1:60)
    at eval (linux.js?d488:2)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/linux.js (renderer.js:12686)
    at __webpack_require__ (renderer.js:712)
    at fn (renderer.js:95)
    at eval (auto-detect.js?3cc7:16)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/auto-detect.js (renderer.js:12638)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Problem

The first problem is that `node-bindings`, which `node-serialport` relies on to resolve the path to its Node.js addon, simply doesn't work in Electron. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings/issues/29) for this, and I don't think the associated PR is even a complete fix, since I've done some debugging, and it appears that `fileName` remains `undefined` throughout the whole `getFileName`.

The second problem: even if it somehow found a `serialport.node` somewhere, it wouldn't work after packaging the application for distribution, since the addon itself isn't in the `dist` directory, and Webpack can't just bundle it together with the main JS file.

One could attempt to solve this with [`node-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader), given a correctly working `node-bindings`, but that wouldn't help either, since `node-bindings` uses elaborate heuristics, which Webpack simply can't extrapolate from, when trying to understand what files could be required by its `require`. The only safe thing Webpack could do is include the whole project, "just in case", and that's a certain no-go, obviously, so `node-loader` just doesn't copy anything.

So, we need to replace `node-bindings` and copy `serialport.node` manually.

#### Solution

First, we must grab the addon and put it in `dist`. This needs to be done in main's Webpack build, since the renderer is served as web page, potentially from an in-memory file system (so the `*.node` file may not be emitted to disk, and Electron will never see it). Here's how:

```
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";

const config = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      "node_modules/serialport/build/Release/serialport.node",
    ]),
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Hardcoded, unfortunately, but easy to fix if something changes.

Second, we must substitute `node-bindings` with our own shim, `src/bindings.js`:

```
module.exports = x =>
  __non_webpack_require__(
    `${require("electron").remote.app.getAppPath()}/${x}`
  );
```

`__non_webpack_require__` is self-explanatory (yes, plain `require` won't work, without some trickery, as it's handled by Webpack), and the `require("electron").remote.app.getAppPath()` is necessary because `__dirname` doesn't actually resolve to what one would expect - an absolute path to `dist` - but rather to some directory buried deep inside Electron.

And here's how the replacement is done, in renderer's Webpack config:

```
import { NormalModuleReplacementPlugin } from "webpack";

const config = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /^bindings$/,
      `${__dirname}/src/bindings`
    ),
  ],
  // ...
};
```

And that's it! Once the above is done, and `index.html` + `renderer.js` are being served by some server (or whatever your approach is), and the `dist` looks something like this:

```
dist/
  main.js
  package.json
  serialport.node
```

`electron dist` should "just work".

#### Alternatives

Could potentially get away with adding `node-serialport` as a dependency to the generated `dist/package.json` and just `npm i`nstalling it in there, and marking `serialport` as an external in Webpack, but that feels even dirtier (package version mismatches, etc.).

Another way is to just declare everything as externals, and have `electron-packager` just copy the whole production part of `node_modules` to `dist` for you, but that's a whole lot of megabytes for basically nothing.

Comment: jfc javascript makes we want to kill myself.

Answer (score 3):

I wanna thank @Alec Mev for practically the only answer on the entire internet that truly works and has real knowledge inside. I've spent days troubleshooting issues with webpack and native modules for electron until I tried Alec's answer and it perfectly works.

Just a small addition, that if the native code is being used within the main process and not the renderer (most common case when app security is stronger), the shim needs to be adjusted as following:

```
module.exports = x =>
  __non_webpack_require__(
    `${require('electron').app.getAppPath()}/${x}`
  );
```

Comment: I got this error: Cannot find name '__non_webpack_require__'.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Alec Mev` answer is amazing, at the time of written.

In my case, all of the internet suggested hacks (like copying, loaders, etc..) was unsuccessful and really unclear.

I wanted to call my own native node addon through electron renderer, but as mentioned by Alec Webpack doesn't handle the .node file as required. So in my case:

Folder structure

```
Electron project dir
│   electron.main.js
│   package.json
│
├───Addon
│   │   addon.js
│   │   package.json
│   │
│   └───dist
│           addon.node
│
└───render-site
    │   index.html
    │   js.js
    │   webpack.config.js
    │
    └───build
```

- THIS IS DEMO - `render-site` is your webpack site, `dist` is your addon binary location.

Very important is to set webpack target to `'electron-renderer'`, it allow you to use require of `electron` and other node modules like `fs` much more easily.

In your site call the addon like the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#remoterequiremodule) suggested

```
const addon = require('electron').remote.require('./addon/dist/addon.node');
```

That's it. You can run the webpack and serve the site while using the addon.

Production is very straight forward, you just make sure to copy the addon to the build of electron (I'm using electron-builder copying system) with the relative path to electron.main.js.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when tried to use a native module in `electron-renderer`.
Although the error message was something like this in my case:

> node-loader: The specified module could not be found

I believe it's all related to node loaders. For me, [native-addon-loader](https://github.com/toyobayashi/native-addon-loader) was the loader that worked great.
Also, make sure your Webpack target is either `node`, `electron-main` or `electron-renderer`, otherwise it won't work (native modules can't be used on the client side).

Comment: What module are you using that has a native addon in it? I suspect it isn't `node-bindings`-based, if it works without employing `externals` or something like that.

Comment: It's `win-audio`. It worth mentioning that I had to install `node-gyp` as well in order to build it.

Comment: Okay, yeah, `win-audio` doesn't use `node-bindings`, it references the `.node` file statically, you're lucky :D